# Algorithms in Continuous Variable Quantum Computing

Tags: quantum-algorithms, resource-request, continuous-variable

I have recently been exploring Continuous Variable Quantum Computing. I would like to know if there are any resources or literature I can read to get a general understanding of how one can extend Discrete Variable Quantum Algorithms to the continuous regime. So far, I have come across [[1](https://arxiv.org/pdf/quant-ph/0002082.pdf),[2](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2107.02151.pdf),[3](https://arxiv.org/pdf/quant-ph/0207108.pdf)], but I would like to see a more generalised procedure in detail if at all possible. It would also be nice if someone could provide some insight into the matter. Thanks!